# When using localStorage in javascript, keeps returning null despite having defined the key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set an item in local storage on one page using the following code:

`localStorage.setItem("move1s", JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("move1").textContent));`

When I try to retrieve it with the following code, it says it returns a null error:

`document.getElementById("specNickname").textContent = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("move1s"));`

This is odd because when I try doing the following, it prints out perfectly fine so clearly the key is identifiable:

`console.log(localStorage.getItem("move1s"));`

I know I'm using localStorage wrong but I don't know what I'm doing wrong specifically. If more code is needed to be posted please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: does `document.getElementById("move1").textContent` returns you the JSON Object ?

Comment: Share the console log of document.getElementById("move1").textContent)

Comment: it seems that your `textContent` is a regular string that is not in JSON format. Therefore, `JSON.parse` returing an error

Comment: Learn more about [JSON Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#)

Answer (score 1):

**How to use local storage if you wanted an example:**

Saving

```
aObj = {name: "TEST",city: "LONDON"};

aJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);

localStorage.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);
```

Retrieving

```
text = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");

obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = obj.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
localStorage.setItem("move1s", JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("move1").textContent));
```

`=> "Text in node"`

JSON.parse needs a JSON object, not a JSON formated string.
The error you should be seeing in the console is something like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

because the first character it sees is the T in Text.
You need to wrap your text to stringify in braces `{}` and make it a valid JSON Object to parse back in

```
var move1s = {(document.getElementById("move1").textContent))}

localStorage.setItem("move1s", JSON.stringify(move1s)};
```

`=> {"Text in node"}`